# Pros and cons of HDF5 and Avro for stocking Images

Tags: python, julia, hdfs, avro, hdf5

I have to stock dynamically monochromes images (specifically Array of Uint16) with a framerate of aproximately 50Hz.
So I'll need a file format allowing me to stock efficiently on my hard drive 2D array of Uint16 data with a (relatively) high frequency. After some researches, I'm planning to use either HDF5 or Avro as a file format. But which one is the best suited to my needs ? Do you have other suggestions than HDF5 and Avro ?

- Binary data (2d Array of Uint16)
- "High" Framerate (50hz, thus ~200Mo/s)
- Julia and C++ handle
- "Big" Allocation for the files (each acquisition could be around 1-2 Go)

Comment: Wouldn't video formats wouldn't be a better option?

Comment: Currently I need no get as data as possible, and process each frame separately, so raw images seems more convenient

Comment: There seem to be some missing words in your comment that make it a bit hard to parse.

There is always a tension between efficiency and convenience. There is also always the question of whether you will can suffer lossy compression for the same reason.

As far as efficiency is concerned (if your images are highly correlated and especially if you can allow just a touch of lossy compression) video formats will win hands down.

As far as convenience is concerned, seeking to a particular frame in a video file is at least as easy as using HDF5 or Avro for random access.